# UnboundLocalError at /index/register/ .local variable 'context' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

local variable 'context' referenced before assignment.I need a explaination
**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from memoster.forms import UserForm, UserProfile
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse

# ----LOGIN---- #
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.urls import reverse


  def home_index(request):
        return render(request, 'home_index.html')


 def index(request):
       return render(request, 'index.html')


def register(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfile(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
           user = user_form.save()
           user.set_password(user.password)
           user.save()

           profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
           profile.user = user
           profile.save()
       else:
           print(user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)
  else:
     user = UserForm()
     profile = UserProfile()
     context = {'user': user, 'profile': profile}

  return render(request, 'registration.html',context)


   def user_login(request):
       if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
         password = request.POST.get('password')

       user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

         if user:
           if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('memoster:index'))
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Account Not active")
    else:
        print("username{} and password {}".format(username, password))
        print("Invalid credentials")
else:
    return render(request, 'login.html')


@login_required
 def user_logout(request):
           logout(request)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home_index'))
```

**traceback**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpAyN.png)

Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/register/
Django Version: 3.1.1
Exception Type: UnboundLocalError
Exception Value:
local variable 'context' referenced before assignment
Exception Location: C:\Users\Faris\PycharmProjects\djangoProject3\memoster\views.py, line 40, in register
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Faris\PycharmProjects\djangoProject3\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3
Python Path:
['C:\Users\Faris\PycharmProjects\djangoProject3',
'C:\Python38\python38.zip',
'C:\Python38\DLLs',
'C:\Python38\lib',
'C:\Python38',
'C:\Users\Faris\PycharmProjects\djangoProject3\venv',
'C:\Users\Faris\PycharmProjects\djangoProject3\venv\lib\site-packages']

Comment: Your indentation is off so it's hard to tell exactly what's going on, but you never set `context` if `request.method == 'POST'` is true.